# Iterating through sub-element `sections` of GeoJSON on a Leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have the following code which I use to display a marker on my map with a popup containing the `feature.properties.name` element from my GeoJSON:

```
var featuresUTMGroundHazards = L.geoJson(dataGuardianUTM, {
    filter: FuncGroundHazards,
    style: setStyle,
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) { return L.marker(latlng, { icon: L.icon({ iconUrl: feature.properties.iconUrl, iconSize: [25, 25], }), }) },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(
            "<b>" + feature.properties.name + "</b>"
            + "<br />"
            );
    },
});
```

If they are present in the GeoJSON, I wish to expand this and itterare through any and all available `properties.display.sections` elements and include the `title` and `text` elements from each, within the marker popup.

I have tried the following code but it displays `undefined` where I would expect some text to be.

```
var featuresUTMGroundHazards = L.geoJson(dataGuardianUTM, {
    filter: FuncGroundHazards,
    style: setStyle,
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) { return L.marker(latlng, { icon: L.icon({ iconUrl: feature.properties.iconUrl, iconSize: [25, 25], }), }) },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(
            "<b>" + feature.properties.name + "</b>"
            + "<br />"
            + "<br /><b>Title:</b> " + feature.properties.display.sections.title
            + "<br /><b>Text:</b> " + feature.properties.display.sections.text
            + "<br />"
            );
    },
});
```

I would have expected that to simply display the first one it found, but it does not.

What do I need to change here in order to itterate through all/any of the `sections`?

The GeoJSON is structured as:

```
{
  "geometry": {
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -0.58585870265960693,
          51.223640441894531
        ],
        // etc...

      ]
    ],
    "type": "Polygon"
  },
  "id": "8A7183778EF92F2FB1A84F5C02A7C233ED71B048",
  "properties": {
    "hazardFactor": "40",
    "hazardFactorName": "Warning",
    "fillColor": "#ffbb00",
    "strokeColor": "#b88702",
    "fillOpacity": "0.35",
    "strokeWidth": "1",
    "strokeOpacity": "0.8",
    "detailedCategory": "amenity:university",
    "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.altitudeangel.com//v1/map/icon?icon=amenity_university.png",
    "name": "University of Law, Guildford",
    "category": "groundHazard",
    "filters": [
      {
        "name": "Ground Hazards",
        "property": "show",
        "active": true
      }
    ],
    "display": {
      "category": "Ground Hazard",
      "detailedCategory": "University",
      "title": "University of Law, Guildford",
      "sections": [
        {
          "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.altitudeangel.com//v1/map/icon?icon=amenity_university.png",
          "title": "Pedestrian Hazard",
          "text": "It is likely that members of the public will congregate in and/or around this area. Please be mindful of their safety."
        },
        {
          "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.altitudeangel.com//v1/map/icon?icon=amenity_university.png",
          "title": "Privacy Concerns",
          "text": "This classification of area or point is likely to be additionally sensitive to privacy concerns. You may have greater obligations to disclose your intended flight over, within or near these areas to any controlling authority or land owner, particularly if you plan to fly with surveillance equipment."
        },
        {
          "iconUrl": "https://aa-ne-prod-public-api.altitudeangel.com//v1/map/icon?icon=warning.png",
          "title": "Summary",
          "text": "Yellow zones indicate regions where operation of your drone may raise security, privacy or safety concerns."
        }
      ],
      "actions": []
    }
  },
  "type": "Feature"
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at GeoJSON structure, you'll see that `feature.properties.display.sections` is not a single object but an array of objects, so you have to reference it's elements as array elements:

```
var popupTxt = "<b>" + feature.properties.name + "</b>";

for (var i = 0; i < feature.properties.display.sections.length; i++) {
  popupTxt = popupTxt
    + "<br />"
    + "<br /><b>Title:</b> " + feature.properties.display.sections[i].title
    + "<br /><b>Text:</b> " + feature.properties.display.sections[i].text;
}

layer.bindPopup(popupTxt);
```

Comment: Ah, it was the whole array concept I was missing from this. Your example worked perfectly, thanks @TomazicM